# Power Button Creating Issue in AndEngine Game

Tags: android, andengine

I developed a game in andEngine which is almost final. Only problem I am facing now is that when during GamePlay if power button is pressed and Game is resumed again It starts from star. Suppose I am playing Level 6 and I pressed power button when the game will be resumed it will start from Level 1. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: You mean that pressing the power button so the `Phone option` interface appears, then pressing the back key to resume game play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save current state in [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and load it in [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

Check this link: [Android activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

Specifically:

- [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)
- [Saving activity state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState)

Answer (score 0):

The main activity detects when it is being paused and taken out of memory.  Look into the Activity onPause() and onResume().

Comment: already handled these two but no result.