# AndEngine application restarts when 'power button' is pressed

Tags: android, andengine

I have written an application that plays music, using AndEngine. The annoying problem is that, when user presses power button or when screen automatically turns off, after pressing power button again, the application restarts and does not resume. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024507/game-restarts-after-power-button-click-in-andengine)  and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950918/power-button-creating-issue-in-andengine-game), but they did not help me. Would you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add this line to your manifest file where you declared your activity

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"

for e.g

```
<activity android:name="com.algo.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Your AndEngine game has at least one Activity.

Each Activity has own lifetime cycle from *onCreate* to *onDestroy*. Take a look at picture and very detailed article here: [Activities Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle)

Your game activity go though cycles and die automatically when user pressed *PowerButton* or *BackButton*. When you turn power on then activity starts from begin (*onCreate*).

You should implement *save* and *load* game functions and save game state on *onPaused* callback and load game state *onResume* callback. It will prevent from loosing state of your game between activity restarts.

Another good article about managing states for Android games: [More Android Games that Play Nice](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/more-android-games-that-play-nice.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found that this problem occurs in the following scenarios:

your Android phone is in portrait mode and your AndEngine application is in landscape mode, or
your Android phone is in landscape mode and your AndEngine application is in portrait mode.

Try to make your application's orientation consistent with your Android system.